# Understanding the heavy quark limit

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

In QCD one often studies the theory in energy scales where only the the 3 lightest quarks are considered for the theory which are the $u,d$ and $s$ quarks out of the six quarks. While the others are said to "not contribute to the dynamics". I understand that the up, down and strange are the lightest that are comparable to the energy scale, but why does it mean to ignore their dynamics?

I'm not very clear as to how exactly, why and in what context other quarks can be ignored? I mean, is it that they don't contribute to the amplitudes? I would greatly appreciate if you can explain this some precise equations.

Comment: You are tossing around  statements without context, and asking around for *others* to provide context for you? In QFT, heavy scales contribute as *p/M* or *E/M* to the amplitude/Feynman-diagram: forget about quarks and think 4-Fermi theory for the weak interactions. In low energy QCD, the heavy quark contributions to *anything* contribute likewise, so  systematic perturbative corrections in *p/M* . As the energy of context grows, [HQET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_quark_effective_theory) negotiates non-perturbative corrections. Is it intrinsic charm you wish to understand?

Comment: Dear Sir, I'm sorry if i'm not able to get my point through. Basically, I wish to understand the relation between energy scale and the dynamics of quarks in the theory? I've come across statements like "the other heavier quarks don't contribute to the dynamics and hence we can ignore them in our Lagrangian and consider the only the 3 lightest quarks u,d,s" which is what I don't entirely understand. I apologize if this isn't sufficient for providing a cohesive answer.

Comment: The statement you quote assumes you understand the concepts of [Effective Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_field_theory), namely how any relative amplitude dependence on heavy masses M, essentially from dimensional analysis, is suppressed by powers of *p/M*.

Comment: Read section 6 of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9806303).